# Length of return value from a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I have a small program that accepts one or more lists, randomizes the contents, and then prints them out.

```
import random


def randomize(*seq):
    shuffled = list(seq)
    for i in shuffled:
        random.shuffle(i)
    return iter(shuffled)


colors = ["red", "blue", "green", "purple"]
shapes = ["square", "circle", "triangle", "octagon"]

for i in randomize(colors, shapes):
    print(i)
```

It works as is.

What I would additionally like is to be able to get a len() on the return value.

- If I do `len(randomize(colors))` I should get back `4`.
- If I do `len(randomize(colors, shapes))` I should get back `8`.

I am getting this error: `Expected type 'Sized', got 'Iterator' instead`.

Was looking at `len()` versus `__len__` but I am just not sure how to address this.

Comment: Why are you using `iter` here? Why not just return the sequence? An iterator doesn't necessary have a set number of elements that it produces (it can be infinite), so it doesn't necessarily make sense to check the size of one. Checking the size would force the iterator to run potentially forever.

Comment: The problem is caused by the use of `iter()`. To get what you want, don't use `iter()`; just return the list (i.e. `shuffled`).

Comment: Without iter(), the error does goes away, but, the count is wrong.  I get back 1 and 2, not 4 and 8.  I am getting the number of lists, not the total number of elements.

Comment: @MarkS the number of lists *is the number of elements*. Adding `iter` does nothing to change that. I'm not sure why you added it in the first place. It seems you want to add all the items inside the objects passed as arguments to your function to a new list. That is what you should do, and just shuffle and return that list.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the `iter` call from the return. The loop will work without it.

```
def randomize(*seq):
    shuffled = list(seq)
    for i in shuffled:
        random.shuffle(i)
    return shuffled

colors = ["red", "blue", "green", "purple"]
shapes = ["square", "circle", "triangle", "octagon"]

randomized = randomize(colors, shapes)
print('number of lists', len(randomized))
print('total number of elements', sum([len(l) for l in randomized]))

for i in randomized:
    print(i)
```

To avoid the need to sum up the returned lists, you need to change the return value of `randomize` and this depends on what you want as a result. Simplest change would be just to concatenate the lists after they are shuffled.

Comment: Otherwise, you cannot have both, something iterable and something with length information. Yes you can. It just so happens that list-iterators don't have lengths, but `list` objects, which are iterable, do have lengths. This is sort of a nitpicky point, but getting the terminology right is important

Comment: This returns 2, not 8. Same issue as before.  I am getting back the total number of lists, not the total number of elements in the lists.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Right, no need to use iter at all here. I was to fast here, will be correcting.

Comment: @MarkS Unless you change your specification, this is correct. Your are receiving two lists in return, thus the length 2. The summed up length is a different thing. I'll add a line to show how to get the total length over all lists.

Comment: Not quite sure how my specification is inaccurate.  I need to pass in any number of lists, randomize the elements, then print.  That part is working.  I also need to be able to print the total length of all elements of all passed in lists via the syntax: len(randomize([passed in lists]).

Comment: @MarkS `len` cannot do this. At least not as long as `randomize` is returning shuffled lists as it does now.

Comment: @mkiever, Is there a way to return the randomized list elements in such a way as to allow len() to return the total length of the list elements?  I am not married to randomize().  It's just how I initially solved the issue of returning randomized list elements.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188639/discussion-between-mkiever-and-marks).

Comment: Not a big deal here, but `res = res + random.shuffle(i)` doesn't work because `random.shuffle` returns `None` and modifies it's argument in-place. Even if it did return a list, this is an anti-pattern. You should use `res.extend(shuffled_sublist)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this - it concatenates your lists and shuffles them afterwards

```
import random
import itertools

def randomize(*seq):
    shuffled = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(seq))
    random.shuffle(shuffled)
    return iter(shuffled)


colors = ["red", "blue", "green", "purple"]
shapes = ["square", "circle", "triangle", "octagon"]

res = list(randomize(colors, shapes))
for i in res:
    print(i)

print('length: {}'.format(len(res)))
```

If you don't want that, this also works:

```
import random
import itertools

def randomize(*seq):
    shuffled = list(seq)
    for i in shuffled:
        random.shuffle(i)
    return iter(shuffled)


colors = ["red", "blue", "green", "purple"]
shapes = ["square", "circle", "triangle", "octagon"]

length = len(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable( randomize(colors, shapes))))
print('length: {}'.format(length))

for i in randomize(colors, shapes):
    print(i)
```